# How to remove value from array in Firebase when I delete the row from tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tableview where is displayed array from Firebase. I need when I delete row from tableview to delete value from Firebase array.

Here is my code, but it gave me an error message:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x114b66dd0) to 'NSArray' (0x114b66448). 2021-04-05 15:32:20.045614+0200 My Wedding Day[8355:287880] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x114b66dd0) to 'NSArray' (0x114b66448). (lldb)

I'm new in swift so this isn't familiar with me.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let guest = guestList[indexPath.row]
        refGuests = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("tables").child("guestsOnTable")
        refGuests.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let guestsOnTable = snapshot.value as! [String]? {
                for i in 0..<guestsOnTable.count{
                    if guestsOnTable[i] == self.uid {
                        self.refGuests.child("userInfo").child(self.uid!).child("tables").child("guestsOnTable").child("\(i)").removeValue()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.guestList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.guestsOnTableTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYuY3.png)

Comment: what error message ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan  Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x114b66dd0) to 'NSArray' (0x114b66448).
2021-04-05 15:32:20.045614+0200 My Wedding Day[8355:287880] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x114b66dd0) to 'NSArray' (0x114b66448).
(lldb)

Comment: You can't delete a single element from an array in the Realtime Database (well, you can but it's not what you think). You will need to read the array in, modify it, and write it back out. Read [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete a single element from an array in the Realtime Database (well, you can but it's not what you think).

You will need to read the array in, modify it, and write it back out.

Arrays in the Realtime Database are actually single objects and the 'indexes' you would normally see in an array are fixed data. If array index 2 is deleted from Firebase, it's literally gone and nothing will replace it e.g. there will be no more value with an index 2 - it will be 0, 1, 3...

One solution is to change your structure and code.

```
guests
   userInfo
      uid_0 //someones uid
         tables
            guestsOnTable
               -Y8sjaoisjasdij89 //created with .childByAutoId - the firebaseKey
                  guest_name: "Kenny"
               -JY8hjoismosmooa
                  guest_name: "Dolly"
```

and when when populating the tableView dataSource, load the each guest from Firebase and store it in a class object

```
class GuestClass {
   var firebaseKey = ""
   var name = ""
}
```

and store those objects in an class level array which will be the dataSource for the tableView

```
var guestArray = [GuestClass]()
```

and lastly, when the user delete's row 1, look up that object in the array via the index

```
let myGuestToDelete = self.guestArray[rowNum] //rowNum = 1 in this case
let keyToRemove = myGuestToDelete.firebaseKey
```

and then build a firebase ref based on that firebase key to remove it

```
let guestsRef = self.ref.child("guests") //self.ref points to my firebase    
let userIdRef = guestsRef.child("userInfo").child(the uid)
let refToRemove = child("tables").child("guestsOnTable").child(keyToDelete)
refToRemove.removeValue()
//and remove it from the array
```

Something to note as well; be careful about how deeply nested your database is; deep references can lead to issues down the road. Consider breaking out your guests onTable to a higher level separate node.

[.childByAutoId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists) creates a unique node key

Comment: Thanks! I have just one question. Because I'm new in Swift, I don't know how to save selected rows with own autoID, that's why I use array. Can you explain how to save to Firebase selected row with own ID? Like this in you example '   guestsOnTable
               -Y8sjaoisjasdij89 //created with .childByAutoId - the firebaseKey
                  guest_name: "Kenny"
               -JY8hjoismosmooa
                  guest_name: "Dolly" '

Comment: @BetYx It's a Firebase feature and is offered in both the Realtime Database as well as Firestore. To create a node in the RTDB with a unique Firebase generated key, use .childByAutoId. For example, to create a node with `Hello, World` as the value; `someRef.childByAutoId().setValue("Hello, World)` - will create a child node in someRef of `-Yuhi88789jska: Hello, World` where the -Yuhi88... part is a 'random' node key. It's covered in the Getting Started guide [Updating or deleting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data)

Comment: @BetYx It's also covered more thoroughly here [Reading and writing lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data)